# What is the difference between onAfterGetMenuTypeOptions and onBeforeRenderMenuItems plugin triggers

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, system-plugin

Both of these plugin triggers have been mentioned by [@Craig](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/107/craig) in his reply to [another question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3588/can-the-access-list-of-a-front-end-menu-item-be-limited-to-certain-user-groups), but what they actually do is not so clear.

In `/administrator/components/com_menus/models/menutypes.php` you have:

> ```
> // Allow a system plugin to insert dynamic menu types to the list shown in menus:
> JEventDispatcher::getInstance()->trigger('onAfterGetMenuTypeOptions', array(&$list, $this));
> ```

In `/administrator/components/com_menus/views/items/view.html.php` you have:

> ```
> // Allow a system plugin to insert dynamic menu types to the list shown in menus:
> JEventDispatcher::getInstance()->trigger('onBeforeRenderMenuItems', array($this));
> ```

1. Can anyone explain what is the difference betweeen these two triggers? From the comments in the code it makes you think they do the same thing.
2. Rather than add a menu type, would it be possible to remove?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between any plugin triggers is the timing at which they run. `onAfterGetMenuTypeOptions` is triggered after the menu types are returned, and `onBeforeRenderMenuItems` is triggered just before the menu items are rendered.

The comment in the code is really just a copy and paste issue (hopefully it'll get fixed).

Comment: The onAfter and onBefore bit I get. I was wanting to understand better what each function does. As I understand it onAfterGetMenuTypeOptions allows you to add more menu types when you are creating menu items for the joomla frontend menus. Is there possibility to remove a menu type option?

Instead the onBeforeRenderMenuItems is not so clear to me. Does this allow us to add an actual menu item to the joomla backend menu?